# Are there implementations of algorithms for community detection in graphs?

Tags: graph, graph-theory

I am looking for implementations of community detection algorithms, such as the Girvan-Newman algorithm (2002). I have visited the websites of several researchers in this field (Newman, Santo, etc.) but was unable to find any code. I imagine someone out there published implementations of these algorithms (maybe even a toolkit?), but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: See: [matlab-networks-toolbox](https://github.com/ivan-brugere/matlab-networks-toolbox)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Community detection algorithms are sometimes part of a library (such as [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) for java) or a tool (see [Gephi](http://gephi.org/)). When authors publish a new method, they do sometimes make their code available. For example, the [Louvain](http://sites.google.com/site/findcommunities/) and [Infomap](http://www.mapequation.org/mapdemo/index.html) methods.

Side note: Girvan-Newman algorithm is sometimes still used, but it has mostly been replaced by faster and more accurate methods. For a good overview of the topic, I recommend [Community detection algorithms: a comparative analysis](http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.1062) or the longer [Community detection in graphs](http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.0612) (103 pages).

Answer (score 30):

You should have a look at the [igraph library](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/):

- 7 community detection algorithms (including those mentionned above):

  - Edgebetweenness (Girvan-Newman link centrality-based approach),
  - Walktrap (Pons-Latapy random walk-based approach),
  - Leading Eigenvectors (Newman's spectral approach),
  - Fast Greedy (Clauset et. al modularity optimization),
  - Label Propagation (Raghavan et. al),
  - Louvain (Blondel et. al, modularity optimization),
  - Spinglass (Reichardt-Bornholdt, modularity optimization),
  - InfoMap (Rosvall-Bergstrom, compression-based approach).
- Other related functions: process modularity, deal with hierarchical structures, etc.
- Available in R, C and Python
- Open source

To my opinion, the most complete tool for community detection.
For more details, also check: [What are the differences between community detection algorithms in igraph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471906/what-are-the-differences-between-community-detection-algorithms-in-igraph/9478989#9478989)

Comment: It's also available in Mathematica now: https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM  All community detection functions are covered.

Answer (score 7):

You can try the SNAP library (Stanford Network Analysis Platform, http://snap.stanford.edu/), which includes Modularity, Girvan-Newman and Clauset-Newman-Moore algorithms. It's written in C++, and is under the BSD licence. As a number of papers have used it (see, http://snap.stanford.edu/papers.html), it should be good.

Answer (score 2):

We have recently implemented [our algorithm](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep14339), which is based on Constant Potts Model, fast Louvain optimization, and reliable map equation of InfoMap for weighted and signed networks. [Here](https://github.com/pouyaesm/signed-community-detection) is the open source java project + an executable jar.

Comment: this helps, many thanks! but still one small question, why your partion output is the sorted index? The expected will be a 2d array, like [[1,2,3],[4,8]] which indicates 1,2,3 is a community

Comment: We used "node_id   group_id" instead of "group_id   node_id1,...", this is an easier representation for automated processing