# Hierarchical community detection with igraph

Tags: r, igraph, hierarchical-clustering

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471906/what-are-the-differences-between-community-detection-algorithms-in-igraph) discussion, edge-betweenness and fastgreedy community detection methods are mentioned as hierarchical method. I am trying to collapse communities to single nodes for analyzing aggregate interation between communities. I started with multilevel or lovain method (Blondel et al.) for a start, assuming it is a hierarchical method. But I am not able to get the dendogram for the same. I guess it is not a hierarchical procedure and I may have to use one of the above two procedures instead.

Any other hierarchical community detection procedure that I can explore?

Comment: This is probably a better discussion to have on cross-valdiated

Comment: How does one migrate a question. Should I simply delete it from here, and post it in cross-validated. Thanks!

Comment: The original question was in stackoverflow, so I just followed suit.

Comment: `as.dendrogram()` gives you a dendrogram.

Comment: Thanks, @GaborCsardi. I will use the dendogram to collapse nodes at each stage.