# What is membership in community detection?

Tags: r, data-mining, igraph, random-walk

I am finding it hard to understand what membership and modularity returns and why is it exactly used.

```
wc <- walktrap.community(karate)
modularity(wc)
membership(wc)
plot(wc, karate)
```

for the above code I get the following when I execute `membership`:

```
[1] 1 1 2 1 5 5 5 1 2 2 5 1 1 2 3 3 5 1 3 1 3 1 3 4 4 4 3 4 2 3 2 2 3
```

for the above code I get the following when I execute `modularity`:

```
[1] 0.3532216
```

I read the documentation but still a bit confusing.

Comment: Relevant post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471906

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of `walktrap.community` is a partition of your graph into communities which are numbered with id's from 1 to 5 in your case. The `membership` function gives a vector of a community ids for every node in your graph. So in your case node 1 belongs to community 1, and node 3 belongs to community 2.

The partition of the graph into communities is based on optimizing a so called modularity function. When you call `modularity` you get the final value of that function after the optimization process is complete. A high value of `modularity` indicates a good partition of the graph into clear communities, while a low value indicates the opposite.

Comment: Thanks,  Is it possible for us to manually set the modularity?

Comment: I don't think so. Modularity is a metric which you get as a result of partitioning the graph into communities. Many partitions can result into the same modularity score so you wouldn't know which to pick.