# R: community detection on directed graph with (negative) weights

Tags: r, igraph

I am analysing a directed, weighted network with R igraph. The network is based on a correlation matrix, i.e. weights go from -1 to +1. This network is clearly undirected, but I am also interested in more general cases.

Based on this network I would like to perform a community detection to group "similar" nodes together. I know there is a whole bunch of community detection methods in R igraph.
See for example [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/summary-of-community-detection-algorithms-in-igraph-0-6/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471906/what-are-the-differences-between-community-detection-algorithms-in-igraph/).

But none of these cases deals with negative weights.

Is there an implementation in igraph (or in some other R package) which can deal with directed networks which have negative weights? Any hints are very appreciated.

Comment: Add 1 to the weights and have them go from 0 to 2 ?

Comment: Well, I wonder if this would bias the community detection algorithm. A weight of -1 means strongly anticorrelated nodes whereas by adding 1 to the weights this would be zero - i.e. no link between the nodes.

Comment: I think you want to use the `abs` of your weights or square them (i.e. use R^2). To me, a weight is a measure of strength, not direction. That is: two nodes connected by a weight of -1 is of equal importance as a weight of 1 because both represent a 1-to-1 relationship between the two variables albeit in different directions.

Comment: I was thinking more of something like this: https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.80.036115     There is a Python implementation which can deal with this sort of problem: https://github.com/vtraag/louvain-igraph  But I couldn't find somehting similar for R

Comment: `cluster_spinglass` handles negative weights

Answer (score 0):

Not 100 % sure, if it violates any assumptions, but as a workaround I set all negative edge weights to zero before calculating [Louvain community detection](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-5468/2008/10/P10008) with `igraph` in R. At least, they are never included in community relationships.

```
E(g)$width <- ifelse(E(g)$width < 0, 0, E(g)$width)
g.louv <- cluster_louvain(g, weights = E(g)$width)
```

**Note:** this applies only to undirected graphs (I overlooked this detail of the question, sorry)

Comment: as far as I know `cluster_louvain` in `igraph` does not handle directed weighted graphs.

Comment: I mean, from the `cluster_louvain` manual of `igraph` 1.2.5:

`weights: Optional positive weight vector. If the graph has a weight edge attribute, then this is used by default. Supply NA here if the graph has a weight edge attribute, but you want to ignore it. Larger edge weights correspond to stronger connections.`

[Also, the algorithm was developed for weighted networks](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-5468/2008/10/P10008).

Comment: weights work (obviously). It doesn't work on weighted directed networks (would need to change the definition of modularity). Maybe there is something out there, but it hasnt been implemented in igraph r, yet.

Comment: Very true indeed! I overlooked this, sorry. Do I better delete my answer then? ...

Comment: I would leave it, maybe somebody will find it useful