# A table comparing 11 igraph community detection algorithms in R

Tags: r, igraph, network-analysis

Not a question but a contribution.
Having used igraph for a few years, I have not yet come across a summary table indicating which community-detection algorithm is best for which network configuration. The table below provides this comparison. Hope it helps!
[image]