# Clustering algorithm for unweighted graphs

Tags: graph, cluster-analysis

I am having unweighted and undirected graph as my network which is basically the network of proteins.I want to cluster this graph and divide this graph in to disjoint clusters. Can any 1 suggest clustering algorithms which i can apply on the biological network which is unweighted and undirected graph.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there implementations of algorithms for community detection in graphs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822265/are-there-implementations-of-algorithms-for-community-detection-in-graphs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several graph partitioning algorithms exist, they use different paradigm to tackle the same problem.

The most common is the [Louvain's method optimizing Newman's modularity](https://perso.uclouvain.be/vincent.blondel/research/louvain.html).
In python using Networkx as graph library you can use [community](http://perso.crans.org/aynaud/communities/api.html) to partition your graph.

The fastest graph partitioning uses [Metis](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/metis/overview). It is based hierarchical graph coarsening.

You also have [N-cut](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~efros/courses/AP06/Papers/boykov-iccv-01.pdf) originally designed to segment images.

Finally, you can partition graphs using [stochastic block-model techniques](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2008/cmsc828g/Slides/block-models.pdf). A very good python implementation of Louvain and several block-model techniques can be found in [Graph-tool](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/community.html#graph_tool.community.minimize_blockmodel_dl).

My favorite is the latter, it is fast (based on the Boost graph library), relatively easy to use and tuneable.

EDIT: Note that in graph-tool, what we call Louvain modularity is indeed Newman's algorithm, the [docs are here](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/inference.html#graph_tool.inference.modularity).