# how can I translate efficiently a Java code to python?

Tags: python

I would be greatfull if you could tell me how one can translate a code from Java to python.
Should one do it manually ? is there any tool to convert it automatically?

Comment: Found a useful tool to achive the conversion of java code to python - https://www.codeusingjava.com/tools/java2py

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to translate java code to python you have to translate it manually. Automatic conversion generally does not have the appropriate quality. It looks like there are some tools out e.g. [java2python](https://github.com/natural/java2python/) but the author states

> The generated Python code is not guaranteed to run, nor is guaranteed to be syntactically valid Python.

Converting a library to another programming language is never an easy task.

If you simply want to use a java library in a application that you want to write in python you could give [jython](http://www.jython.org/) a try.

Comment: is it possible to invoke Java inside python ? my mean I use the Java code by I run it under python ?

Comment: @nik It looks like there are some tools out there that do automatic translation of java to python code like [java2python](https://roundrockriver.wordpress.com/2007/02/15/automated-translation-of-java-to-python/). But (currently) no automatic tool will easily produce good, maintainable, idiomatic code. What exactly is your usecase?

Comment: Why can't you manipulate and understand it in java?

Comment: I get your point, so probably the best is to just write the code myself from the begining and not try to translate it because it is very time consuming and sometimes very complicated. however, I liked your answer and I accept it bro. THANKS

Comment: because it is long time i did not use Java which even I don't know how to run that code :-p

Comment: If you understand the algorithms (I certainly do not!) writing python code yourself might be viable. If you just want to play with the code you could try jython, which executes python in a java context (so you can import the library). If you actually need to do some work maybe you will be able to find python libraries (e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31694167/clustering-algorithm-for-unweighted-graphs)). But in the end sadly there is no easy answer. Java isn't that complex (syntaxwise) so if you get it to build it shouldn't be too hard. Good luck!

Comment: would you mind to like my question?

Comment: I think **java2python** was only for Python 2 (both runtime and output language).  I can't get pip nor pip3 nor conda to install in into any Python 3 environment.